# O MySQL está embutido no EasyPHP?

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

Utilizo EasyPHP e instalei somente ele, o PhpMyAdmin funciona perfeitamente e consigo manusear perfeitamente as tabelas.

A instalação do MySQL já é embutida no *localserver* que utilizo ou algo do gênero? Preciso instalar algum outro software mais para ter um desempenho melhor?

Comment: Geralmente esses pacotes instalam o, apache, mysql, php e configuram o modulo do php no apache.

Comment: melhorar o desempenho? Você esta tendo problemas de performance? Não consegui entender a situação aqui. É uma pergunta hipotética e não um problema real?

Comment: É mais uma pergunta hipotética para eu conhecer melhor como funciona essa ferramenta que utilizo, desculpe se não deixei claro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O EasyPHP instala tudo o que você precisa para aprender usar um servidor web, incluindo o MySQL. Você não precisa nada além disto, embora pode querer outras coisas depois.

Com o aprendizado vai saber o que pode lhe ajudar mais e fará com que não queira mais usar este tipo de *bundle* de software. Ele é ótimo para ajudar quem não sabe nada, mas é péssimo para uso normal. Ele facilita o uso justamente escondendo o que pode dar mais desempenho e flexibilidade.

Sugiro fuçar bastante em tudo o que foi instalado para começar aprender um pouco mais profundamente como funciona e depois dar o passo de não precisar deste tipo de software e poder ter mais controle sobre o que está usando. A curiosidade é fundamental para evolução.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, ajudou a entender melhor o que estou usando.

Answer (score 1):

**PhpMyAdmin** é somente a interface de administração do banco de dados MySQL. Você pode verificar que na pasta de instalação do EasyPHP tem a pasta do MySQL. Mas nada impede você de instalar o **MySQL Workbench** (que é o conhecido MySQL, quando na verdade é também somente uma interface/ferramenta de administração do banco de dados - funciona similarmente ao **SQL Server *[Versão]* Management Studio** que é a ferramenta do SQL Server, onde "management" quer dizer "gestão" ou "administração").

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 1):

Um programa de gerenciamento de banco de dados não vem no pacote de instalação do EasyPHP ou de outro programa de servidor, tipo Wamp, Xampp e Apache.

Dá para baixar a parte um programa que gerencie um banco de dados. Alguns deles:

- MySql Workbench (já citado, free e bom)
- MySql Browser (bom)
- Navicat (eu uso esse no Windows, porém não é free)
- Toad (bom e free)

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, irei procurar sobre eles.